# How to append the value of a checked radio button to a seperate element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add the value of the checked radio button to a seperate element?
So when the radio button "#quantity2" gets checked I like to replace the "100" with "200".

```
<input type="radio" id="quantity1" name="quantity" value="100" checked>
<input type="radio" id="quantity2" name="quantity" value="200">
<input type="radio" id="quantity3" name="quantity" value="300">

// Add the value of the checked radio button here
<div id="cart-animation">100</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('input[name=quantity]').click(function(){
    $('#cart-animation').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="quantity1" name="quantity" value="100" checked>
<input type="radio" id="quantity2" name="quantity" value="200">
<input type="radio" id="quantity3" name="quantity" value="300">

<div id="cart-animation">100</div>
```